# a simpler way to sum up each value

Tags: python

```
# total payments = the sum of monthly payments
# object-level method for calculation in Loan class
    def totalPayments(self):
        # the monthly payment might be different depending on the period
        t = 0  # initialize the period
        m_sum = 0  # initialize the sum
        while t < self._term:  # run until we reach the total term
            m_sum += self.monthlyPayment(t)  # sum up each monthly payment
            t += 1  # go to next period
        return m_sum
```

monthly payment might be different depending on different period, so instead of simply multiplying it by term, I chose to sum up each payment individually. Is there a easier way of doing this?
I thought to do this at first

```
sum(payment for payment in self.monthlyPayment(t) if term <= t)
```

But t is not initialized and won't be incremented to calculate each payment. So I was wondering if there is any easier approach that could possibly achieve the above functionality in a single line or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `t` increments by `1` each time, so why don't you use a `range` object?

```
for t in range(0, self._term): # You can omitt the 0
    ...
```

So, if you want to mantain your `comprehension`, the best way should be this:

```
sum(self.monthlyPayment(t) for t in range(self._term))
```

Comment: In the original code, presumably they want `range(self._term)` as well (no need for `0`, and the `+ 1` would be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but you need to iterate over `t`s here, and `range` lets you bake in the end condition:

```
sum(self.monthlyPayment(t) for t in range(self._term))
```

or if you like using `map` (slightly less verbose since you've already got a method doing what you want, if less familiar to some, and perhaps trivially faster by avoiding bytecode execution during the loop):

```
sum(map(self.monthlyPayment, range(self._term)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the proper statement would be

```
sum(self.monthlyPayment(t) for t in range(self._term))
```

Answer (score 1):

`self.monthlyPayment(t)` doesn't return a sequence that you can iterate over. You need to loop over the range of arguments to this function and call it for each.

```
sum(self.monthyPayment(t) for t in range(self._term))
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it.

```
m_sum = sum(self.monthlyPayment(t) for t in range(self._term))
```